# Display article content with matching url's in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Building a post area for a news app powered by newsapi which should display a particular article with its properties, with 'url' matches rather than 'id' matches. For now i want it to display article content, if there is one, else it should display an error message, in this case "Error loading article". Its just displaying Error loading article.

Here's what i've done:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Post extends Component {
 constructor () {
   super();
   this.state = {
     post: [
       {
         url:"",
         content:"",
         author:"",
         publishedAt:"",
         title:"",
         urlToImage:""
       }
     ]
   };
 }

componentDidMount() {
  let url = this.props.match.params.post_url;
  fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
        'country=us&' +
        'apiKey=fe76e3e41c7647358505016dad4f958a' + url )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({post :response.articles}));
}
  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;
    const postcard  = post ? (
        <div class="card card-cascade wider reverse">
          <div class="view view-cascade overlay">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={post.urlToImage} alt="Card image cap"/>
            <a href="#!">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title"><strong>{post.title}</strong></h4>
            <h6 class="font-weight-bold indigo-text py-2">{post.author}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{post.content}</p>
            <p><a class="px-2 fa-lg li-ic">Source:{post.source}</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    : (
      <div class="center">Error loading article.</div>
  );

    return (
      <div class="container">
        <h2></h2>
          {postcard}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing props passed into this component

```js
  let url = this.props.match.params.post_url;
```

But,

```js
class Post extends Component {
 constructor () { // no props
   super(); // no props
   this.state = {
     post: [
       {
         url:"",
         content:"",
         author:"",
         publishedAt:"",
         title:"",
         urlToImage:""
       }
     ]
   };
 }
```

You aren't passing in the props received from the parent component. Thus, `this.props.match.params.post_url` will always be `undefined`, and concatenating `undefined` to a string literally appends the string "undefined" to the end of it. Thus your url becomes malformed and the response set into `this.state.post` will not match the JSON schema you expect. Probably will be an error response from the API.

Comment: Passing in props in the constructor and super still makes post undefined

Comment: For `this.state.post` to evaluate as falsy, `response.articles` must be `undefined` or a similar value. Can you make a reproducible example including the parent component on a platform like [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/zKRGpo)? What matters here is the value of the `url` at the end of your request string.

Comment: @KelvinYelyen Can you use the link I provided to see how to make a _reproducible_ example? Pasting the same code from here into Codepen is not helpful.